Angular 16 HighCharts Not Working with API
Angular 16 does not work over the highcharts API.I can't understand exactly what mistake I made here. There is no problem with the data coming from the API. When I add data to the array myself, I see that the graph works. But I can't draw the data coming from the API. I hope you can help me with this.
Product Service:
 GetProductsHighcharts(): Observable<GetProducts[]> {
    return this.httpclient.get<GetProducts[]>('https://localhost:7131/api/products/').pipe(
      map((data) => data),
      catchError((error) => throwError(error))
    );
  }
  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return throwError(error.message || "server error.");
  }

List Component:
ngOnInit() {

    this.getProducts();
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

    this.productService.GetProductsHighcharts().subscribe((data: GetProducts[]) => {
      this.chartOptions = {
        title: { text: 'Values' },
        xAxis: {
          categories: data.map(d => d.productName)
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: { text: 'Series' }
        },
        series: [{
          type: 'line',
          data: data.map(d => d.startBrix),
          name: 'startBrix'
        }]
      };
    });
}

  
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    title: {
      text: 'Dynamic Data from API'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: []
    },
    series: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        data: []
      }
    ]
  };

Html:
  <div id="container" style=" display:flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; flex-direction: column;">
    <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions">
    </highcharts-chart>
    <p>{{chartOptions | json}}</p>

  </div>



My problem was that the methods in ngoninit were not running asynchronously. Now everything is fine.
